# Equal sign in data "causes" BeginGetRequeststream to fail

Tags: c#, asynchronous

The line marked in the code below (//THIS IS THE ASYNC CALL).  Will not call the async call back if I pass in this value as the query to my function:

```
<Verb>get</Verb><ResourceList><CatalogQuery><ItemQueryList><ItemIDList><ID>16-=-cedar-bonsai</ID></ItemIDList><AttributesType>all</AttributesType></ItemQueryList></CatalogQuery>
```

Note this part of the xml:

```
<ID>16-=-cedar-bonsai</ID>
```

However it works if I switch the equal sign to anything else

```
<Verb>get</Verb><ResourceList><CatalogQuery><ItemQueryList><ItemIDList><ID>16-here-cedar-bonsai</ID></ItemIDList><AttributesType>all</AttributesType></ItemQueryList></CatalogQuery>
```

Whats really confusing me is that the contents of the query should have absolutly no effect on the callback being called. Right?

Here is the code

```
//Get get a item attributes Async
        public XElement makeAsyncCall(string query,bool create = false,bool resent = false)
        {

            ManualResetEvent mre = null;
            //The results will be stored here;
            StringBuilder xresults = new StringBuilder() ;

            sem.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                query = query.Replace("&", "&amp;");
                query = query.Replace("#39;", "apos;");

                //If this is not a query that is being sent again append additional info
                if (!resent)
                {
                    query = HEADER_TEXT + query + CLOSER_TEXT;
                }

                //Concatonate a declaration, header information, the query to be performed, and the closing XML tag. Then convert to a Byte array
                Byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                            new XDocument(
                                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
                                XElement.Parse(query)
                            ).ToString()
                );

                string paddr = POST_ADDRESS_QUERY;
                if (create != false)
                {
                    paddr = POST_ADDRESS_CREATION;
                }

                //Setup the post connection 
                HttpWebRequest httpWReq = WebRequest.Create(paddr) as HttpWebRequest;
                httpWReq.Method = "POST";
                httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                httpWReq.Proxy = null;
                httpWReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
                httpWReq.KeepAlive = true;


                using (mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
                {


                     //THIS IS THE ASYNC CALL
                     httpWReq.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(getRequestStreamAsync), Tuple.Create<HttpWebRequest, byte[], bool, StringBuilder, ManualResetEvent>(httpWReq, byteData, create, xresults, mre));
                    mre.WaitOne(10000);
                    mre.Close();

                    //Try again if not exited already.
                    if (xresults.Length == 0)
                    {
                        httpWReq.Abort();
                        sem.Release();
                        return makeAsyncCall(query, create, true);
                    }

                    sem.Release();
                    return XElement.Parse(xresults.ToString(), LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                mre.Close();
                sem.Release();
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The content *could* affect the result, e.g. if you had an unescaped `<` or `>` in the text, but I don't see why `=` would be a problem.  Try loading the XML in Internet Explorer and see if it complains.

Comment: But I am only requesting a stream not executing the query. So the query has not even been sent over the connection before it hangs.

Comment: @EricJ. Internet Explorer does not complain about the equals sign.

Comment: Be aware that `throw (ex)` discards the original stack trace and says your method threw the exception instead of what originally did. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you. I will find a way to wrap  the catch In a finally instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the issue. The callback was being executed but it was not causing breakpoints to stop. This morning I tried the code again and the breakpoints were being caught. I am not sure if this is a bug in visual studio or undefined behavior? Maybe someone else knows more about visual studio in that regards.

The requests where going through fine and receiving responses but later in my code I was generating my own exceptions, catching them, throwing them, and then retrying the command. So it was stuck in a infinite loop.

Comment: I have had this happen when a Antivirus had a lock on my `pdb` file during the build so the file was out of date so the breakpoints did not work.

Comment: Interesting, I have had issues with "ghost" breakpoints that I removed refusing to go away every time I run the debugger. My solution was to just delete the pdb file and restart. Perhaps the two issues are related. I don't think in my case Microsoft security essentials would have a lock on the file (though I guess its possible)

Comment: If you are having "Ghost" breakpoints check that you don't have two `.cs` files that have the same name but are in different folders or loaded projects. The breakpoint database only uses the file name and line number the breakpoint is on even though the full name appears to be stored if you right click on a breakpoint, if you have two files with the same name in different folders or loaded projects it will break on every file that has the same name.